# Evaluating a limit for a damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: limits

Given the formula for the displacement amplitude $A(\omega)$ of a damped harmonic oscillator of mass $m$, natural frequency $\omega_0$ and width $\gamma$. It is driven by a force $F$.
$$A(\omega)=\frac{QF_0}{m}\frac{1}{\omega_0\omega}\sqrt{\mathcal{R}(\omega)}$$
where we have:
$$\mathcal{R}(\omega)=\frac{\gamma^2\omega^2}{(\omega^2_0-\omega^2)+(\gamma\omega)^2} \ \ \ Q=\frac{\omega_0}{\gamma} \ \ \ F=F_0cos(\omega t)$$
Examining the behaviour of this function as $\omega \to 0$ and as $\omega \to \infty$, we evaluate the limit via cancelling the two omega terms to end up with:
$$A(\omega)=\frac{QF_0}{m}\frac{1}{\omega_0}\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{(\omega^2_0-\omega^2)+(\gamma\omega)^2}}$$
Then evaluating $$\lim_{\omega \to 0}A(\omega)=\frac{F_0}{k}, \ \ \ \text{where k is a constant.}$$
Similar steps are taken to evaluate as $\omega \to \infty$. I then proceeded to attempt to examine the behaviour of the acceleration amplitude function as $\omega \to \infty$. , given as:
$$A_{acc}(\omega)=\frac{QF_0}{m}\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\frac{\gamma\omega}{\sqrt{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\gamma\omega)^2}}$$
However, I can't seem to be able to evaluate this limit. Would I be correct to attempt to use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: It looks to me like that limit is infinite, but linear asymptotically.

Comment: I thought the same, but the answer is supposed to be $\frac{F_0}{m}$

Comment: Oh right, I see it. $(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)$ should be $(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2$.

Comment: What method might I use to evaluate it now?

Comment: Multiply and divide top and bottom by the necessary power of $\omega$ that lets you write the entire expression terms of $1/\omega$'s.  Then the limit will be clear, because all of those $1/\omega$'s go to zero.  That's the standard tricks with rational functions, and if you square this, you've got a rational function, so it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need L'Hôpital's rule, have that for $\omega \to \infty$

$$A_{acc}(\omega)=\frac{QF_0}{m}\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\frac{\gamma\omega}{\sqrt{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\gamma\omega)^2}}=\frac{\omega_0}{\gamma}\frac{F_0}{m}\frac{1}{\omega_0}\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{\omega_0^2}{\omega^2}-1\right)^2+\left(\frac{\gamma}{\omega}\right)^2}} \to \frac{F_0}{m}$$